# Published artifacts for Spring Integration Extensions

Tags: maven, spring-integration

I am interested in including [Spring Integration Extensions](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-extensions) into my project, particularly the zip file project for working with zip files across flows.

I can't find anywhere in the GitHub repo or on Maven any sort of indication this work was ever published.

Was it published, and if so, where? And if not, anybody know why? Was it just a sample/documentation project perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its latest version is here: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/integration/spring-integration-zip/2.0.0/. Maven Central in other words.

It’s a bit shame we couldn’t migrate this Zip extension project to the core Spring Integration for `6.0` version like we did with some others, but I promise you that it will make it into `6.1` next year.

Comment: Nice! And thanks for clarifying here!